# Can you "apply" a function to a "package" of arguments in Swift somehow?

Tags: swift, function

I was wondering if there's a function (or special syntax) which would behave something like the hypothetical `apply` below (but for arbitrary `f`; the one given here is just for the sake of example):

```
func f(a: String, b: String) -> Bool {
    return a == b
}

let argDict = ["a": "foo", "b": "bar"]

apply(f, argDict) // evaluates f(a: "foo", b: "bar") and returns false
```

It doesn't have to use a dictionary for the arguments (maybe it even *can't* use a dictionary?); it could use some other datatype or even just some other special syntax, as long as it somehow enables you to **package up arguments** and then **apply a function to them later**, as though you had written the arguments in by hand.

If not for all functions, what about for special classes of functions, like functions with variadic arguments? For example, it would be nice to be able to apply a function with signature `(Double...) -> Double` to an array of type `[Double]` as though we had inlined the values.

And if it doesn't already exist as a built-in, can it be constructed?

(Also, I'm not looking to redefine `f`; if you wanted to, I think you could just redefine it via `f1(dict: [String: String]) -> Bool { ... }` and then use `dict["a"]` and `dict["b"]` in the body instead in place of `a` and `b`. But I'm asking this question because I'm curious about the language capabilities here, not because I'm trying to solve a specific problem.)

Comment: Not in Swift. If you need that sort of introspective dynamism, use ObjectiveC.

Comment: @matt Hmm, gotcha. Not even for variadic arguments somehow? It seems pretty natural to want to apply a function to a preexisting array at least in that case. (I edited the question to include this case.)

Comment: No. How would it determine at compile time whether `argDict` had all the correct parameters of the correct types? If it didn't, what should happen? Should it crash? (This is explicitly the kind of thing that Swift tries to avoid.)

Comment: are the argument names and types consistent every time? Then you can make a struct and pass it to the function

Comment: @RobNapier Well, you couldn't with dicts, I guess. But it *could* be the case that for each function `f`, there's an associated...class?struct? which you might call `args(f)`, which would be inhabited only by objects which supplied valid argument patterns. This could be checked at compile time, as long as the only way to construct an element of `args(f)` required that we provide appropriately-typed parameters for each label. So it's not impossible *in principle* to have some kind of "argument package" while still doing compile-time checks and avoiding what Swift wants to avoid...I think. No?

Comment: @atultw do you mean that one could redefine `f` to take in a struct as opposed to two parameters `a` and `b`, or is there a way to pass a struct with fields `a` and `b` to `f` as written?

Comment: @thorimur yes, thats exactly it. Since swift supports overloading you can make another function with the same name that takes `a` and `b` as normal args to support both styles

Comment: Swift used to have that. You could pass a tuple of the arguments rather than the arguments directly, which is exactly what you're describing (a strongly-typed argument package). It was called "tuple splat." It was removed in Swift 3. See the SE for the background and why it was removed. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md

Comment: "Why is a language this way" questions are often downvoted, usually because it's assumed there is no way to answer it objectively. That's not always true (this one has an objective answer), but it's a common thought. We get a lot of unanswerable questions in the form "why does Swift have static types that prevent this JavaScript pattern?" The answer is always "because it crashes if you use it wrong, even in JS, and Swift chose to reduce those kinds of crashes" and after a couple of years it does start to wear on answerers a bit. But it's also rude to askers, so I'm sorry it happened.

Comment: @RobNapier Ah, I see. I can understand how this question might have been read as that sort of question at first glance (and how it even sort of winds up requiring a response of that type when answering it fully in the negative: "Swift language designers specifically made the language this way so you couldn't do that, and here's why"). Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift used to have that. You could pass a tuple of the arguments rather than the arguments directly, which is exactly what you're describing (a strongly-typed argument package). It was called "tuple splat." It was removed in Swift 3. See the [SE](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md) for the background and why it was removed.